# How are nested purpose clauses rendered in Latin?

Tags: purpose-clause, composition

How are nested purpose clauses expressed in Latin? For example, imagine we have an idea like "I got up early to go to the store to buy milk." So there are nested clauses of purpose: the reason I got up early was to go the store, and the reason I am going to the store is to buy milk.

Using a double *ut* seems weird. I don't see how I can nest *ut*'s.

Comment: In this particular case you could use a supine for the second clause since "go" is a verb of motion. But it's a good question more generally.

Answer (score 8):

Good Roman composition had no problem with [hypotaxis](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/goodell/parataxis-and-hypotaxis), including subordination within subordination, and you certainly can find examples of nested *ut* clauses, such as in Cicero's *Ad Familiares* 1.10:

> Fac [**ut** quam primum venias neque in Apuliam tuam accedas]<sup>1</sup> [**ut** possimus salvum venisse gaudere]<sup>2</sup>.

Generally, however, there is a tendency by good prose writers to reduce repetition, outside of devices such as anaphora. You'll often find another way of conveying the same information or even whole sentences in order to avoid repetition.

For purpose clauses specifically, you have a few options. TKR has already mentioned the supine for verbs of motion (which takes care of your specific example). You also have the dative of purpose ("I woke up early in order to (ut) go to the store *for milk*") or *ad* + noun + gerundive as possibilities. You could even turn one into a temporal clause or participle ("Waking up early, I went to the store to buy milk", though this feels more Greek than Latin), or you could join the first clause together with the clause on either side of it ("I woke up early *and* went to the store in order to buy milk" or "I woke up early in order to go to the store *and* buy milk").

Pinkster (2015) and Danckaert (2012) have plenty of examples of all of these.

Which is chosen, though, has more to do with style than grammar.